# 上下段のグラフ作成

Tags: python, matplotlib

初歩的な質問で恐縮ですが、matplotlibを使って
・上の段に折れ線グラフと棒グラフを重ね、
・下の段に、上の段と同じX軸で線グラフ
を作る場合はどのようにコーディングすればよいでしょうか

Answer (score 0, accepted):

以下、一例です。その他に [Examples — Matplotlib 3.7.0 documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/index.html) も参考になるかと思います。

```py
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [*range(10)]
data = [random.sample(range(30), 10) for _ in range(3)]
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 1, sharex=True)

ax[0].plot(x, data[0], color='red', label='Data 1')
ax[0].bar(x, data[1], zorder=-1, label='Data 2')
ax[1].plot(x, data[2], label='Data 3')

ax[0].xaxis.set_tick_params(labelbottom=True)
for a in ax: a.legend()

fig.suptitle('Example')
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]